# When should I use a function within a function versus a separate private function?

Tags: f#

When should I use a function within a function versus a separate private function?

**I observed that a function that I wrote was fairly long:**

```
let optionsFor piece (positions:Space list) =

    let yDirection = match piece with
                     | Black _ -> -1
                     | Red   _ ->  1

    let sourceX , sourceY = 
        match piece with
        | Black (checker , pos) -> pos
        | Red   (checker , pos) -> pos

    let optionsForPiece = 
        (fun pos -> pos = ((sourceX - 1) , (sourceY + yDirection)) ||
                    pos = ((sourceX + 1) , (sourceY + yDirection)))

    let availableSelection = 
        (fun space -> match space with
                      | Available pos -> Some pos
                      | Allocated _   -> None)

    let availablePositions = 
        positions |> List.filter toAvailable
                  |> List.choose availableSelection

    availablePositions |> List.filter optionsForPiece
```

Thus, I considered refactoring the function above into several small functions.

However, I am not sure if this is necessary in functional programming.

What is the current recommendation on inner functions versus extracting them out to private functions?

**Appendix:**

```
open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnit

(* Types *)
type Black = BlackKing | BlackSoldier
type Red =   RedKing   | RedSoldier

type Coordinate = int * int

type Piece =
    | Black of Black * Coordinate
    | Red   of Red   * Coordinate

type Space =
    | Allocated of Piece
    | Available of Coordinate

type Status =
    | BlacksTurn | RedsTurn
    | BlackWins  | RedWins

(* Functions *)
let black coordinate = Allocated (Black (BlackSoldier , coordinate))
let red   coordinate = Allocated (Red   (RedSoldier   , coordinate))

let startGame () =
    [ red (0,0);  red (2,0);  red (4,0);  red (6,0)
      red (1,1);  red (3,1);  red (5,1);  red (7,1)
      red (0,2);  red (2,2);  red (4,2);  red (6,2)

      Available (1,3); Available (3,3); Available (5,3); Available (7,3)
      Available (0,4); Available (2,4); Available (4,4); Available (6,4)

      black (1,5);  black (3,5);  black (5,5);  black (7,5)
      black (0,6);  black (2,6);  black (4,6);  black (6,6)
      black (1,7);  black (3,7);  black (5,7);  black (7,7) ] , BlacksTurn

let private toAvailable = 
    (fun space -> match space with
                  | Available pos -> true
                  | _             -> false)

let available (positions:Space list) = positions |> List.filter toAvailable

let optionsFor piece (positions:Space list) =

    let yDirection = match piece with
                     | Black _ -> -1
                     | Red   _ ->  1

    let sourceX , sourceY = 
        match piece with
        | Black (checker , pos) -> pos
        | Red   (checker , pos) -> pos

    let optionsForPiece = 
        (fun pos -> pos = ((sourceX - 1) , (sourceY + yDirection)) ||
                    pos = ((sourceX + 1) , (sourceY + yDirection)))

    let availableSelection = 
        (fun space -> match space with
                      | Available pos -> Some pos
                      | Allocated _   -> None)

    let availablePositions = 
        positions |> List.filter toAvailable
                  |> List.choose availableSelection

    availablePositions |> List.filter optionsForPiece
```

Comment: I wonder if this is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) maybe.

Comment: My code just serves as context. I think the question doesn't even require code. I guess I'm looking for pros and cons for each option.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is what you asking, but this should be dictated by your usage and if you will/want to access the function from the outside (the function and your module and other .NET code). There is nothing wrong with defining many small functions and inner functions, as long as you organize them.

Comment: pros and cons will be highly context dependent....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more opinion-based, but I'll offer my opinion.

My rule of thumb would be that if the "helper" function is **tighly associated** with the "main" function, I'd write it as a nested function. If they're not tightly associated, I'd write the helper function as a separate function -- and I might not even make it private, because you never know when it might come in handy for other code in a different module.

An example of a *tightly associated* inner function would be the kind of loop-with-accumulator function that you often end up writing in recursive functional programming. For example, here's some code I wrote for an F# programming exercise:

```
module BinarySearchTree

type Node<'T> =
    { left: Node<'T> option
      value: 'T
      right: Node<'T> option }

let singleton v = { left = None; value = v; right = None }

let rec insert v t =
    if v <= t.value
        then match t.left with
             | None -> { t with left = singleton v |> Some }
             | Some n -> { t with left = insert v n |> Some }
        else match t.right with
             | None -> { t with right = singleton v |> Some }
             | Some n -> { t with right = insert v n |> Some }

let fromList l =
    match l with
    | [] -> failwith "Can't create a tree from an empty list"
    | hd::tl ->
        tl |> List.fold (fun t v -> insert v t) (singleton hd)

let toList t =
    let rec loop acc = function
        | None -> acc
        | Some node ->
            (loop [] node.left) @ (node.value :: (loop [] node.right))
    loop [] (Some t)
```

Take a look at that last `toList` function. It has an inner function that I called `loop`, which would make no sense as a standalone function. It is so *tightly* associated to the `toList` function that it just makes sense to keep it as an inner function, not accessible from outside `toList`.

However, when I wrote the `fromList` function, I did not define `insert` inside it as an inner function. The `insert` function is useful on its own, quite apart from the functionality of `fromList`. So I wrote `insert` as a separate function. Even though `fromList` is the only function in my code that actually uses `insert`, *that might not necessarily be true* in the future. I might write a `fromArray` function, where I don't want to reuse `fromList` for efficiency's sake. (I *could* write `fromArray` as `let fromArray a = a |> List.ofArray |> fromList`, but that creates an unnecessary list that I'm just going to throw away when I'm done; it makes more sense, efficiency-wise, to directly iterate over the array and call `insert` as appropriate.)

So there's an example of when it's wise to use nested inner functions vs. separate functions in the same module. Now let's look at your code.

- `yDirection` - This is a variable, but could be turned into a function taking `piece` as a parameter. As a function, it looks like it could be useful in many different functions. My judgment: **separate**.
- `sourceX` and `sourceY` - These are variables, not functions, but you could turn that `match` into a function called `source` that returns a tuple, and then call it in your `optionsFor` function to set the values of `sourceX` and `sourceY`. In my opinion, that `source` function makes most sense as a **separate** function.
- `optionsForPiece` - This function looks tightly associated with the `optionsFor` function, such that you probably wouldn't want to call it from elsewhere. My judgment: **nested**.
- `availableSelection` - This could be quite useful in several situations, not just `optionsFor`. My judgment: **separate**.
- `availablePositions` - This is a variable, but could easily be turned into a function that takes `positions` as a parameter and returns which ones are available. Again, that could be useful in several situations. My judgment: **separate**.

So by splitting out all the functions that seem like they could be re-used, we've gotten your `optionsFor` function down to the following:

```
// Functions yDirection, source, availableSelection,
// and availablePositions are all defined "outside"

let optionsFor piece (positions:Space list) =

    let yDir = yDirection piece

    let sourceX , sourceY = source piece

    let optionsForPiece pos = 
        pos = ((sourceX - 1) , (sourceY + yDir)) ||
        pos = ((sourceX + 1) , (sourceY + yDir))

    positions |> availablePositions |> List.filter optionsForPiece
```

That's a lot more readable when you revisit the code later, plus you get the benefit of having more reusable functions (like `availableSelections`) around for when you write the next bit of your code.